blocking all ports except SSH on a machine running a Docker container
I have a virtual machine (let's call it "M") on the cloud where a MariaDB database runs within a Docker container.
The client apps on other machines connect to the database via a SSH tunnel, so the only useful port for that "M" machine is SSH.
I would like to block all other ports on the VM to improve the protection, especially to prevent anyone from directly accessing the database.
I wanted to use iptables, however, as Docker installs several rules, I am confused on how to best do this. I don't want to break anything on Docker rules, and all the documentation I have found so far (such as https://tecadmin.net/how-to-allow-only-ssh-access-using-iptables/) assumes that no other iptables rule have to remain.
Can you please help me achieving this, or point me to an appropriate tutorial?
Also, as the only access to that machine is SSH, I am scared to lose access to it for ever if I do something wrong in the iptables configuration. Is using the "at" command to restore old rules after a few minutes a good and safe practice? Is there anything better?
Many thanks!

Just don't publish the services to the external interface. If you only use SSH tunnels you only need the loopback interface. Publish the ports to 127.0.0.1 and you don't need to worry about iptables.
Docker bypasses other chains in iptables anyway.

Many thanks! this sounds all good, will try that!
If, however in the future, I would like to block the machine ports for reinforced security, that documentation seems useful: https://docs.docker.com/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host.
Then, what about my question about the "at" command, and best practices to test iptables rules before full deployment?

No idea, I never bothered with something like that. just changing iptables rules does not disrupt existing connections. As long as your SSH session is open you can do any tests you want. Additionally, as long as you don't save the iptables rules you only need to reboot to revert them. There are many ways to handle this, it comes down to personal preference, making it off topic here.

just tested the 127.0.0.1:port thing, just works! thanks again
